# Newline added when appending elements to a div

Tags: javascript

The output of code below produces a line of text and then a button below the text.
How can I place the button beside the text?

```
var count = document.createTextNode('My text: ');
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(count);

var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','POST');
f.setAttribute('action','test');

var text = document.createElement('input');
text.setAttribute('type','hidden');
text.setAttribute('name','text');
text.value = 'Hey! - hidden value';

var s = document.createElement('input'); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type','submit');
s.setAttribute('value','Hey!');

f.appendChild(text);
f.appendChild(s);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(f);

s.onclick=function(){
    f.submit();
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/hk0annoq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display attribute of form elements is set to `block` by default, which means that when they're created they'll skip one line within a paragraph. To solve this, one approach would be to make the form's display atrribute to `inline` or `inline-block`:

```
f.style.display = 'inline';
```

Here:

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','POST');
f.setAttribute('action','test');
f.style.display = 'inline';
```

Your [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hk0annoq/1/).

Update:

Expanding epascarello's answer, a more correct approach would be:

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','POST');
f.setAttribute('action','test');

// Create your label
var label = document.createElement('label');

// Set its text
var count = document.createTextNode('My Text: ');

var text = document.createElement('input');
text.setAttribute('type','hidden');
text.setAttribute('name','text');
text.value = 'Hey! - hidden value';

var s = document.createElement('input'); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type','submit');
s.setAttribute('value','Hey!');

// Append your text, hidden input and submit button to the label
label.appendChild(count);
label.appendChild(text);
label.appendChild(s);

// Append the label to the form
f.appendChild(label);

// Append the form to the container
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(f);
```

Because it gives the document better semantics.

Answer (score 1):

What you have

```
<text node - inline>  
<form - block - causes new line>
```

You would need to append it inside the form, not the container.

```
f.appendChild(count);
f.appendChild(text);
f.appendChild(s);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(f);
```

You should also look at using a [label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) since that is how you are treating that text.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than what they say and no CSS needed, look at [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hk0annoq/2/)

You just had to put 'count' inside the form rather than the container

```
f.appendChild(count);
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(count);
```